# Select first occurring element after another element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got the following HTML code on a page:

```
<h4>Some text</h4>
<p>
Some more text!
</p>
```

In my `.css` I've got the following selector to style the `h4` element. The HTML code above is just a small part of the entire code; there are several `div`s more wrapped around belonging to a shadowbox:

```
#sb-wrapper #sb-wrapper-inner #sb-body #myDiv h4
{
    color               : #614E43;
    margin-top          : 5px;
    margin-left         : 6px;
}
```

So, I have the correct style for my `h4` element, but I also want to style the `p` tag in my HTML.

Is this possible with CSS-selectors? And if yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
#many .more.selectors h4 + p { ... }
```

This `+` is called the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where
> E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2
> share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes
> E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

Comment: An alternative is to use JS to find your `h4` elements, walk to the next sibling and add a CSS class to that. With jQuery, this would simply be `$('#sb-wrapper #sb-wrapper-inner #sb-body #myDiv h4').next().addClass('shadowbox-h4-p');`

Comment: Note that this only works on elements following the first one IMMEDIATELY. If you want to have the second next html element, you can chain it up like this:

#selector .original + h4 + p to get the p following an h4 following an .original element. Very usefull

Answer (score 54):

For your literal example you'd want to use the adjacent selector (+).

```
h4 + p {color:red}//any <p> that is immediately preceded by an <h4>

<h4>Some text</h4>
<p>I'm red</p>
<p>I'm not</p>
```

However, if you wanted to select all successive paragraphs, you'd need to use the general sibling selector (~).

```
h4 ~ p {color:red}//any <p> that has the same parent as, and comes after an <h4>

<h4>Some text</h4>
<p>I'm red</p>
<p>I am too</p>
```

[It's known to be buggy in IE 7+ unfortunately](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector).

Comment: Very useful info that ```~``` ... Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Just hit on this when trying to solve this type of thing my self.

I did a selector that deals with the element after being something other than a p.

```
.here .is.the #selector h4 + * {...}
```

Hope this helps anyone who finds it :)

Comment: Using the `*` matches any element as described in the title. Was a helpful reminder for me.

Comment: This is the only answer that fits the question. Other answers require prior knowledge on the type of preceding element.

Comment: Happy I found this answer among the responses doubted there would be a wildcard, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**Simplifying for the beginners:**

If you want to select an element immediately after another element you use the **`+`** selector.

**For example:**

**`div + p`** The `+` element selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements

---

If you want to learn more about selectors use this [table](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score -2):

I use latest CSS and "+" didn't work for me so I end up with

:first-child

Comment: That's for the first child of the element and not the next element.