# How to reference a Div after each h3

Tags: css

If I have something like this

```
<h3><a href="#">Pay Info</a></h3>
    <div id="pay-Wrapper" >
       ...content
    </div>
<h3><a href="#">Car Info</a></h3>
    <div id="car-Wrapper" >
       ...content
    </div>
<h3><a href="#">Loan Info</a></h3>
    <div id="loan-Wrapper" >
       ...content
    </div>
```

How can I reference in css the div after each h3 so I can set a style that I want to apply to all first div after any h3 in my page?

here's what I tied, no luck though:

```
h3 div 
{
    height:100px; 
    overflow-x:hidden; 
    overflow-y:auto; 
    position:relative; 
    left:0; 
    top: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to declare a class?

Comment: why would I need to?  there are only 3 h3s on my page.  I don't need to introduce a class at this point to distinguish unique H3s

Comment: only introduce things as you need it (lean).  If I had other text outside this that had H3 that would be affected by this and I didn't want that to be affected THEN I'd start adding classes to distinguish differences in specific H3s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I reference in CSS the `div` after each `h3` so I can set a style that I want to apply to all first `div` after any `h3` in my page?

Use this adjacent sibling selector...

```
h3 + div {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: thanks I've never used + before, good to know.  I know you can do sometimes [tag] [tag2] (using space) or [tag].[tag2] using a period but never used + before or at least needed to until now...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`h3 + div { ... }`

This is also known as the adjacent [sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

also check out the following: 
[CSS how to select first occurring element after another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623328/css-how-to-select-first-occuring-element-after-another-element)

it is the same question