# Select element based on the child of its previous sibling

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I have this code:

```
<cite>
 <a id="john" href="javascript: void(0)">John</a>
 <span>time</span>
 <a>DELETE</a>
</cite>
<blockquote>hello there</blockquote>
```

This is my CSS:

```
cite #john + blockquote {color:black;}
```

I am aware this won't work but I need something to select only the `blockquote` elements right after a `cite` that contains an anchor with the ID `john`.

I cannot change the HTML only the CSS. Any ideas please?

If this is impossible with CSS then a JavaScript solution would be welcome too.

Comment: There is no `:has()` selector in css, yet.

Comment: You can't select it with css selectors. You need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Your title is not at all consistent with your description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS how to select first occuring element after another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623328/css-how-to-select-first-occuring-element-after-another-element)

Comment: If impossible with CSS then a javascript solution would be welcome too.

Comment: CSS doesn't work this way. There is no [parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/3597276) or [previous sibling selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792/3597276). You'll need JS. (Too bad you didn't also ask for an [`nth-of-class`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/3597276) selector. That would have been pretty cool :-)

Comment: CSS only works in the forwards direction, which is why there is no previous sibling selector. You'll need to use javascript if you can't modify the html directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following jQuery selector to select the desired element.

```
$('cite').has('a#john').next('blockquote')
```

```js
$('cite').has('a#john').next('blockquote').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}

blockquote {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<cite>
  <a id="john" href="javascript: void(0)">John</a>
  <span>time</span>
  <a>DELETE</a>
</cite>
<blockquote>hello there</blockquote>
<cite>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)">John</a>
  <span>time</span>
  <a>DELETE</a>
</cite>
<blockquote>hello there</blockquote>
<cite>
  <a id="john" href="javascript: void(0)">John</a>
  <span>time</span>
  <a>DELETE</a>
</cite>
<blockquote>hello there</blockquote>
```

**Solution Without jQuery:**

```js
var activeClass = 'active';
var cites = document.querySelectorAll('cite');

[].forEach.call(cites, function(elem) {
 if(elem.querySelector('a#john')) {
        var blockQuote = elem.nextElementSibling;
        blockQuote.className = blockQuote.className + activeClass;
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}

blockquote {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<cite>
  <a id="john" href="javascript: void(0)">John</a>
  <span>time</span>
  <a>DELETE</a>
</cite>
<blockquote>hello there</blockquote>
<cite>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)">John</a>
  <span>time</span>
  <a>DELETE</a>
</cite>
<blockquote>hello there</blockquote>
<cite>
  <a id="john" href="javascript: void(0)">John</a>
  <span>time</span>
  <a>DELETE</a>
</cite>
<blockquote>hello there</blockquote>
```

Comment: is it possible with no jquery? Seems like I cant use it here.

Comment: Sorry, now im getting this:  cites.forEach is not a function",

Comment: @CainNuke in which browser you are checking?

Comment: Im on firefox. The jquery code displays fine but not the second one.

Comment: @CainNuke I've updated once again, plz check, It should work.

Comment: Now I can see ti here but I cant reproduce it on my end. Wehre do I put the javascript code? Inside head? Or inside body?

Comment: @CainNuke better place it inside body near its end.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try like that.

Comment: @CainNuke Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzvvgyhp/). Its working in my Firefox 45.4.0.

Comment: Yes, its working with me too. Actually the problem is that I cant get it to work on a Firefox addon that places code on a page. Seems like its a problem with the addon.