# Change styling only if the header comes right after a div with a specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the following markup:

```
<div class="dynamic-div">Just a text</div>
<h3>A Header</h3>

<h3>A Header</h3>

<div class="dynamic-div">Just a text</div>
<h3>A Header</h3>

<h3>A Header</h3>

<h3>A Header</h3>
```

I want to change the colour of a h3 header in red only if it comes right after a div with class **dynamic-div**.

How can I do that with CSS?

Comment: Duplicated question here : [select-first-occurring-element-after-another-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623328/select-first-occurring-element-after-another-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following CSS, the `+` symbol is the adjacent sibling selector

```css
.dynamic-div + h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamic-div">Just a text</div>
<h3>A Header</h3>
<h3>A Header</h3>
<div class="dynamic-div">Just a text</div>
<h3>A Header</h3>
<h3>A Header</h3>
<h3>A Header</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following selector should work:

```
div.dynamic-div + h3{
 color:red;
}
```

Explanation:

- Parent is a `h3` element with the class `.dynamic-div`.
- `+`: The element right after the first one
- `h3`: Apply the style to h3 elements

Comment: The right parent path is : `div.dynamic-div + h3` [select-first-occurring-element-after-another-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623328/select-first-occurring-element-after-another-element)

Comment: Oops, forgot that it was a div and not an h3 element. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CSS Code:

```
   .dynamic-div + h3 {
      color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

For each "H3" add the class "Dynamic-div" and add to the css for that class the line.
color: "red" ; or something similar

Comment: Adding class to h3 only works if you can change the code. It not respond to the question. [select-first-occurring-element-after-another-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623328/select-first-occurring-element-after-another-element)