# Add class next td

Tags: javascript

Can you help me? JS is not my field..
I want to add class of td after an element in td before.
I have this code in table:

```
<td><span class="day event">24</span></td>
<td><span class="day">25</span></td>
```

I need to add td class everytime if in td before is class .event
Next td after .event will be td class "after-event"

Example:

```
<td><span class="day event">24</span></td>
<td class="after-event"><span class="day">25</span></td>
```

And I need it to work even if there is tr between cells
Thanks!

Here is default javascript of WP plugin:

```
   //Build calendar of a month from date
buildCalendar: function (fromDate, calendar) {
  var plugin = this;

  calendar.find('table').remove();

  var body = $('<table class="calendar"></table>');
  var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
  var tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');

  //Header day in a week ( (1 to 8) % 7 to start the week by monday)
  for (var i = 1; i <= this.settings.days.length; i++) {
    thead.append($('<td class="day-name">' + this.settings.days[i % 7].substring(0, 3) + '</td>'));
  }

  //setting current year and month
  var y = fromDate.getFullYear(),
    m = fromDate.getMonth();

  //first day of the month
  var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
  //If not monday set to previous monday
  while (firstDay.getDay() != 1) {
    firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() - 1);
  }
  //last day of the month
  var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
  //If not sunday set to next sunday
  while (lastDay.getDay() != 0) {
    lastDay.setDate(lastDay.getDate() + 1);
  }


  for (var day = firstDay; day <= lastDay; day.setDate(day.getDate())) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    //For each row
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

      //  var td = $('<td><span class="day">' + day.getDate() + '<span class="room-price">12$</span>' + '</span></td>');
      var td = $('<td><span class="day">' + day.getDate() + '</span></td>');
      //if today is this day

      var ymd = day.getFullYear() + '-' + day.getMonth() + '-' + day.getDay();
      var ymd = this.formatToYYYYMMDD(day);
      //  console.log(ymd);
      if ($.inArray(this.formatToYYYYMMDD(day), plugin.events) !== -1) {
        //  console.log('found');
        td.find(".day").addClass("event");
        // tr.find(".test").addClass("event");
      }
      
      

      //if day is previous day
      if (day < (new Date())) {
        td.find(".day").addClass("wrong-day");
      }

      if (day.toDateString() === (new Date).toDateString()) {
        td.find(".day").addClass("today");
        td.find(".day").removeClass("wrong-day");
      }
      //if day is not in this month
      if (day.getMonth() != fromDate.getMonth()) {
        td.find(".day").addClass("wrong-month");
      }

      //Binding day event
      td.on('click', function (e) {
        // /alert('ok');
      });

      tr.append(td);
      day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1);
    }
    tbody.append(tr);
  }

  body.append(thead);
  body.append(tbody);

  var eventContainer = $('<div class="event-container"></div>');

  calendar.append(body);
  calendar.append(eventContainer);
}
```

Comment: Post the JS you've tried please

Comment: Have you considered using the "CSS element+element Selector"? ([adjacent sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623328/select-first-occurring-element-after-another-element))

Answer (score 0):

If your `event` class is added only with your js code you posted on line:

```
  if ($.inArray(this.formatToYYYYMMDD(day), plugin.events) !== -1) {
    td.find(".day").addClass("event");
  }
```

Just add this line after it:

```
  if ($.inArray(this.formatToYYYYMMDD(day), plugin.events) !== -1) {
    td.find(".day").addClass("event");
    td.find(".day").parent().next().addClass("after-event");
  }
```

That will use same if logic you have to setup `event` class on `td`, and search for next sibling of that same `td` and class to it...

```js
$("td").find(".day").addClass("event");
$("td").find(".day").parent().next().addClass("after-event");
```

```css
.event {
  color: blue;
}

.after-event *{
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="day">24</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">25</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```